# MinGW gcj for Windows?

Tags: gcc, mingw, gcj

I can't find the link to the binaries for gcj for MinGW; it doesn't show up on the MinGW-get list, and I can't find the binaries on [the site](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Compile_with_gcj).

Does it even exist? Where can I find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/BaseSystem/GCC/Version4/gcc-4.5.2-1/), you'll see the text:

> The Java language is absent, pending resolution of build issues.

That's for gcc 4.5.2. It seems to be missing from *all* the 4.5 streams.

There's some Java stuff in the [4.4 stream](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/BaseSystem/GCC/Version4/Previous%20Release%20gcc-4.4.0/) if you want to check that out.

Answer (score 7):

Just because the MinGW website doesn't build GCJ doesn't mean nobody else does. Look at http://www.thisiscool.com/gcc_mingw.htm where they have Windows binaries. I've just tested it and it works like a charm, even allows libgcj to be statically linked.